# Enumerable regular space is $0$-dimensional

Tags: general-topology

This is probably a stupid question, but I could not figure out a solution.

Let $X$ be a topological space. If $X$ is enumerable and regular, then $X$ is $0$-dimensional.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not a stupid Q.................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Use the fact that a regular Lindelöf space is normal and hence completely regular. (I’m assuming here that for you *regular* implies $T_1$, so that singletons are closed, and Uryson’s lemma gives you the functions required for complete regularity. In the terminology that I prefer, *regular* just means that points and closed sets not containing them can be separated by disjoint open sets, and a space that is both regular and $T_1$ is a $T_3$ space.)

Now let $x\in X$, and $U$ be any open nbhd of $x$. By complete regularity there is a continuous $f:X\to[0,1]$ such that $f(x)=0$, and $f(y)=1$ for all $y\in X\setminus U$. Show that there is an $\alpha\in(0,1)$ such that $f^{-1}\big[[0,\alpha)\big]$ is clopen.

**Added:** Suppose that $X$ is regular and countable but not $T_0$. For $x,y\in X$ write $x\sim y$ if and only if $x$ and $y$ have exactly the same open nbhds; $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $X$. Let $Y=X/{\sim}$; then $Y$ is $T_0$, and it’s not hard to show that if $X$ is regular, then so is $Y$. A regular $T_0$ space is $T_3$, and $Y$ is certainly countable, so $Y$ is zero-dimensional. It’s not hard to check that a clopen base for $Y$ pulls back to a clopen base for $X$, so the result actually holds for regular spaces, not just for $T_3$ spaces.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just to confirm. You're picking $\alpha$ such that no $x \in U$ satisfies $f (\alpha)$, right? Furthermore, will this result fails if $X$ is not $T_1$? I suspect it will fail by using the cofinite topology.

Comment: @user40276: Yes, any such $\alpha$ works. I didn’t actually think about whether $T_1$ is required. The cofinite topology isn’t a counterexample, though, because it’s not regular. Actually, any regular $T_0$ space is $T_1$, so a counterexample would have to fail to be even $T_0$. Let me think about that for a bit.

Comment: @user40276: One has to work a bit harder, but the result is actually true for all regular spaces; I’ve added a sketch of the proof to my answer.